# Android - Access class in phone.apk

Tags: android, class, android-activity, apk

Hi guys this is just my first post,
is it possible to access an activity which is in Phone.apk in a non-rooted phone?

I've tried something like this

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        i.setClassName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.PhoneApp");
        startActivity(i);

but my app always stops unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no activity named `com.android.phone.PhoneApp` in the Android firmware, let alone in the Android SDK.

Moreover, you should not be attempting to start activities in the `com.android` package, as they are not part of the Android SDK and may or may not exist on any given device or Android version.

Comment: Thanks, can't give reputation. I've just seen com.android.phone.PhoneApp is not an activity. What if I'd like to start an activity only on my device? For instance com.android.phone.FakePhoneActivity. Is my code right?